# "The volume cannot be downgraded" error when attempting upgrade to macOS Ventura 13.4

Tags: macos

I am trying to upgrade from macOS Ventura 13.0 to macOS Ventura 13.4 and I keep getting the following error. I have no idea how to proceed and fix this issue

[image]